# Linking MySql Database to Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, mysql-workbench, azure-mysql-database

I have a Database using MySql, however i want to migrate to azure MySql which i know is possible, I am new to Azure.

**My question if i make changes to the local database, is it possible to automatically update the tables in azure with same changes?**

I want to link both Database together and any changes effected on any will affect the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is available and is called Data-In replication. Please see: [How to configure Azure Database for MySQL Data-in Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/howto-data-in-replication) for instructions on how to configure this functionality. Please see the [Limitations and Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-data-in-replication#limitations-and-considerations) but the following are the requirements:

- The master server version must be at least MySQL version 5.6.
- The master and replica server versions must be the same. For example, both must be MySQL version 5.6 or both must be MySQL version 5.7.
- Each table must have a primary key.
- Master server should use the MySQL InnoDB engine.
- User must have permissions to configure binary logging and create new users on the master server.
- If the master server has SSL enabled, ensure the SSL CA certificate provided for the domain has been included in the `mysql.az_replication_change_master` stored procedure. Refer to the following [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/mysql/howto-data-in-replication#link-master-and-replica-servers-to-start-data-in-replication) and the `master_ssl_ca` parameter.
- Ensure the master server's IP address has been added to the Azure Database for MySQL replica server's firewall rules. Update firewall rules using the [Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/mysql/howto-manage-firewall-using-portal) or [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/mysql/howto-manage-firewall-using-cli).
- Ensure the machine hosting the master server allows both inbound and outbound traffic on port 3306.
- Ensure the master server has a **public IP address**, the DNS is publicly accessible, or has a fully qualified domain name (FQDN).